# SPOT6 image does not display correctly in arcpad

Tags: image, arcpad

I am using  ArcPad Data Manager from Arcmap 10.3 to export SPOT6 image to .apm file for Arcpad, and using it for field work, I exported it as background TIFF, the projection I used is :WGS_84_UTM_zone_23N.  Everything was fine, but the image display somehow changed, I thought it because of SPOT6 has 4 bands, I composite them with first three bands, I also exported the image as GRID format, but none of them works. You can see clear difference between two images(below).Can anyone tell me how to figure this out?

[image: The left side picture is original image display in Arcmap(very clear image), the right side picture is the image exported and opened in ArcPad(more whiteness and less clear than original one)]

Comment: sorry for did not say that I am using ArcPad 10.
The left side picture is original image display in Arcmap(very clear image), the right side picture is the image exported and opened in ArcPad(more whiteness and less clear than original one)